# Python Stored Pickle How Can File Size be so Small?

Tags: python, performance, storage, pickle

for a project Im doing in Python I saved a list of ~25K Python objects (dataclasses with more than 30 attributes each and no methods) which resulted in a lovely .obj file of just 150kB! This means that each object stored in the .obj file only takes up about 6 Bytes. Now Im left wondering how on earth Python can store this data so efficiently since each integer is stored using 32 bits (4 Bytes) and these objects clearly have more than 1.5 integers in them. Can anyone tell me what Im missing or how Python does this so efficiently?

Im on Ubuntu and I did check on Mac and an external HDD if the file size differed, but it did not. The way of storing the pickle was done using:

```
with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(data_list, file)
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me out!

Comment: @sj95126 I've tried to pickle a random array and one with only zeros with the same length and the sizes are the same

Comment: Ah thank you @sj95126, I just checked the data and there indeed don't seem to be many unique values. Does this mean that for data with quite a bit of duplicate values (e.g. financial market data) using a pickle is more efficient than for example CSV files?

Comment: From the documentation: “… The pickle module keeps track of the objects it has already serialized, so that later references to the same object won’t be serialized again”

Comment: Maybe try `dill` instead? It seems to handle custom dataclasses better.

Comment: The real question.  Read the data back in.  Are you seeing exactly what you expected?  In that case, don't worry about what Python is doing internally.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I checked and although all data was there, there were a lot of duplicate objects. The data arrives asynchronously and I assumed all new data would be different compared to earlier received data but this was apparently not the case which caused many duplicates to be saved. I did get the same results as @jvx8ss for the numpy arrays so it does not always seem to be the case.